# How to check column for range value and render specific value in corresponding cell if it is within range

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have an excel column with an age group and the next column states if they are a young adult (18 - 30) or an adolescent (1-17), the age group is column H and the one next to it is column I, I'm trying to figure out the IF statement so I can render either "young adult" or "adolescent" if it is within either ranges in column H.

For example if H2 is 24 the cell next to it would render "young adult".

If I could get some help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

`=IF(H1<=17,"adolescent", IF(H1<=30,"young adult","adult"))`

It checks - step by step the age - and returns your expected result.

If you want to be flexible regarding the ranges, it might make sense to put the ranges into an extra table like this:
[image]

Then you can use this formula:

`= XLOOKUP(H2,$A$2:$A$3,$B$2:$B$3,"adult",1,1)`

Whenever you change the ranges in column A - the new group is shown in column I.

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there an If statement I can add if the cell is empty so it dosen't write anything?

Comment: just remove `adult` but keep the quotation marks: `=IF(H1<=17,"adolescent", IF(H1<=30,"young adult",""))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the <kbd>SWITCH( )</kbd> Function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
    α, A2:A5,
    SWITCH(
        TRUE,
        α = "", "",
        α <= 17, "Adolescent",
        α <= 30, "Young Adult",
        "Adult"
    )
)
```

---

Or, With <kbd>LOOKUP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(φ, A2:A5, IF(φ="","",LOOKUP(φ,{1,18,31},{"Adolescent","Young Adult","Adult"})))
```

---